# Laravel 5.1 Form Request Validation

Tags: validation, laravel-5.1

When you create a manual validator in laravel you can attach callbacks to be run after validation is completed as follows:

```
$validator = Validator::make(...);

$validator->after(function($validator) {
   if (!Auth::validate(['email' => Auth::user()->email, 'password' => $this->input('old_password')]))
   {
       $validator->errors()->add('old_password', 'Invalid password');
   }
});
```

How can you do the same inside a Form Request i.e. where do you add the above call back function in the form request example below?

```
class AccountRequest extends Request
{
     public function authorize()
     {
          return true;
     }

     public function rules()
     {
        return [
            'new_password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6';
            'old_password' => 'required';
        ];
     }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reference to the comments, you need to validate that the Old Password is equal to the existing field in DB, as well, the New Password = Confirmed Password.

To accomplish that, first build a customer validator for Old Password:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Validator;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Validator::extend('existing', function($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
            return  \Hash::check($value, User::find($parameters[0])->password);
        });
    }

    /**
     * Register the service provider.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Then in your Form Request:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Http\Requests\Request;

class FormRequest extends Request
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'old' => 'existing:'.\Auth::user()->id,
            'password' => 'confirmed|required_with:old'
        ];
    }
public function messages()
{
    return [
        'old.existing' => 'Wrong old password'
    ];
}


}
```

Comment: I've already tried this but I get error `ReflectionException in Container.php line 572: Class App\Http\Requests\ValidationService does not exist`

Comment: That's the problem, the blog is using the beta version of Laravel 5, so things changed.

Comment: May I ask, why you need that? Actually the code in Controller is what should run after validation, so why you need it in the Request?

Comment: I would like to give user the possibility to change password so I have 3 form fields (new_password, new_password_confirmation, old_password). I want to check the users old password with what is stored in the database before allowing to make the update.

Comment: You can do that with simple Form Request, you do not need any after validation

Comment: You can not do it with simple form request becuase you need to check the old password against what is stored in the database. If you can do it with simple form request please provide example?

Comment: using `\Hash::make($value);` does not match the password?

Comment: not error but just return false everytime. I've tried the following using tinker `App\User::find(18)->password == \Hash::make(123456);` but it returns false even though there is a user with id of 18 with password 123456

Comment: Try to inspect each alone, what is the value of App\User(18)->password, and the value of \Hash::make('12345')

Comment: Also are you using the Hash class to hash passwords in your User class or different implementation?

Comment: The hashed values are different. The value of user id 18 is `$2y$10$tDb/IEUw14frzkIIUNFjBuET9SyJWHshaJ6VzXhxfszz1sk3XKDXy` the value of \Hash::make('123456') is`$2y$10$lJgyikIRpHa2h0/C3ELVsuh68Ig/yQ6d9ipGR8rsM1yn3pn0Y1uEa` . I use bcrypt to store hashed password. But even when i try bcrypt(123456) the hash it generates is different each time.

Comment: Then either the password is not 123456 or you are not using Hash class for hashing.

Comment: You also mentioned it 12345 only, then you printed out \Hash::make('123456')

Comment: Your find query is comparing a string value. Using \Hash::make or bcrypt generates a different hashed string each time for the same password hence a simple string comparison doesnt work.

Comment: I'm updating the answer

Comment: That works now. Many thanks. One question though, how do you add a custom error message for this custom validation rule?

Comment: Updated again, please check

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add `public function after($request)`, and check if this works.